# Select multiple items in table and move them with the option of another multiple select

Tags: design-patterns, tables

The users should be able to select multiple items from a table and then have the option to move them to another place which they again must choose from a searchable table.

Also the users should have the possibility to select multiple items in this second table.

Is there a better pattern than showing the second table in an overlay?
Or does anybody know about a website where you can do kind of a similar action?

Thanks for your answers
[image]

Comment: I think we will need a bit more context for your problem before providing a clear answer... what do the icons in the second table represent? Can the items in the first multi-select be moved to multiple locations? What is the overall take the user is trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry for not being precise enough. Also I meant "items" in the second table, not "icons" (autocomplete misspell), sorry! So, the first table is a list of users. You can select multiple users and assign them to multiple projects in the second table. There can be many projects, so you would have to filter the second table with the projects, too. Another option is to move users into pools of users with similar attributes (like moving them into folders). The overall take is to organise users by assigning them to jobs and moving them into folders.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to not show the second tables to select from in an overlay.

Answer (score 1):

you can provide a comparison chart by placing a table on the left side and second table on the right side (by providing an option to compare two tables and transfer rows between them) and then you can either go for multiple selections or can provide the way [trello](http://trello.com) transfer the cards [like this](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/d7c0ad2a2b05dd321baccffaa7d71222c7b58954/68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f72656163742d7472656c6c6f2f626f6172645f73637265656e2e706e67)

[image]

or you can proceed with the way you mentioned as once any row gets selected, there should be options saying transfer to and then a modal shows the possible list to transfer by having comparing data so that judgement could be better.